# Can anyone do this ? How switch the vs-code multiple extension from one language specific extension to another?

Tags: java, python, visual-studio-code

Sometimes I have to work on different programming languages on vs code.
But the issue is I have to disable all the previous extensions which are used in the previous language. This makes vs-code heavy for work 
For example, if I am working on PHP and have to shift on python or javascript then I have to disable all the extension and enable then single by single.

Is there any way in vs-code so I can group the extension and enable that group as I need that.

Comment: You could start with all extensions disabled and then enable them per workspace if that's easier.

Comment: thanks for suggestions @BrettCannon but issue is that if i have to shift on multiple project it become tedious task to disable and enable the one by one

Comment: Sorry, but a little confused, the extensions will conflict with each other? And the different language means a different project? If that is, you can enable or disable the extensions with the scope of 'Workspace'. If not, the extensions work depend on filename extension and I really think you can just let it be.

Answer (score 3):

As of vscode 1.69 Insiders, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72875272/836330 for "settings profiles" which allow you to have different sets of extensions for different projects.  Also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_69.md#settings-profiles

There is an example there specifically about setting up different environments for different languages -

> A Settings Profile comprises of settings, keyboard shortcuts,
> extensions, state, tasks, and snippets. You can customize VS Code for
> different development environments like Web, Machine Learning, or for
> multiple programming language classrooms like Python, Java or for
> personal modes like Work or Demo and save them as Settings Profiles.
> You can open multiple workspaces (folders) with different profiles
> simultaneously based on the projects you are working on or the
> classroom you are attending to or when you are presenting.

---

[Previously, suggest using the above instead.]

This is the same issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98093 (Unique Settings for Different Programming Environments)

There is an intriguing comment there about using the [Settings Sync](https://github.com/shanalikhan/code-settings-sync) extension (not the built-in settings sync) to create different "profiles" - including different sets of extensions - for different programming environments, not necessarily different machines.

And see [Profile Switcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aaronpowell.vscode-profile-switcher#review-details).

Comment: i will check for the these solution's . thank you for your valuable suggestions

Comment: It just remove the extension from the vscode not disabling the extension.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, it isn't ideal.  I don't know how long switching "profiles" would take - maybe it is acceptable.

Comment: yes, in my case i am using some heady extension which takes significant amount of time to download it.

Comment: set workbench.experimental.settingsProfiles.enabled = true